# "TypeError: Unicode-objects must be encoded before hashing" even when password is encoded with bcrypt

Tags: python, flask, unicode, encode, bcrypt

When using bcrypt for a post request i keep getting the following error:

> TypeError: Unicode-objects must be encoded before hashing

Even though i encoded a password in utf-8 as seen in the following code:

```
hashed_pw = bcrypt.hashpw(password.encode('utf-8'), bcrypt.gensalt())
```

Here is the traceback for more information:
[image]

Any help is greatly appreciated :)

Edit:

The function where the code fails

```
def verifyPw(username, password):
    if(not UserExists(username)):
        return False

    hashed_pw = users.find({
        'Username':username
    })[0]['password']

    if(bcrypt.hashpw(password.encode('utf-8'), hashed_pw)==hashed_pw):
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

The request
[image]

Comment: That's not the code in the error.  The code in the error passes `hashed_pw` as the salt.  Is THAT a Unicode string?

Comment: @TimRoberts I added the function where it fails with an image of the request i made in Postman.

Comment: Please [don't post images of code, error messages, or other textual data.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors)

Comment: Please first extract a [mcve] to make sure you understand the actually problematic code, only ask questions here afterwards. You can [edit] your question to fix that still.

Comment: Given that code, isn't the problem obvious?  BOTH parameters to `bcrypt.hashpw` have to be bytestrings.  They BOTH need to be encodec.

Comment: I realized that I was not storing the hash in my database and the actual password in strting, I fixed it and it works now. Thank you for the help :) and I will make sure to not post images next time.

Answer (score 0):

Solved in comments.

Was not storing the hash in the database but rather a password in string which is why it was giving an error.